# Various types of correlation functions in models with random interactions

Tags: statistical-mechanics, correlation-functions, ising-model, randomness

In the Ising model, spin correlations are characterized by the following correlation function
$$
C_{ij} = \langle \sigma_i\sigma_j\rangle - \langle \sigma_i\rangle\langle \sigma_j\rangle
$$
where $\langle\ldots\rangle$ denotes averaging over the Gibbs distribution. In the case where the interaction between spins or with an external field is random, this correlation function is also random and it is natural to introduce additional averaging:
$$
C_{ij} = \overline{\langle \sigma_i\sigma_j\rangle - \langle \sigma_i\rangle\langle \sigma_j\rangle}
$$
where $\overline{\cdots}$ denotes averaging over random external field and interaction. In the latter case, one more correlation function can be defined
$$
D_{ij} = \overline{\langle \sigma_i\rangle\langle \sigma_j\rangle} - \overline{\langle \sigma_i\rangle}\ \overline{\langle \sigma_j\rangle}
$$
This correlation function is equal to zero for non-random models, so it can probably be said that it somehow characterizes the influence of randomness on the physical properties of the model system. But what else is known about the correlation function $D$? Are there any known relationships between the functions $C$ and $D$? Something like
$$
|D_{ij}| \leq |C_{ij}|
$$
or equality of the corresponding correlation lengths. Does the correlation function $D$ reflect the phase transition in the model, as I assume the $C$ correlation function does?